# Maximum call stack size exceeded on post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why I am getting this error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Using the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "#requestData", function(){
  var selectcriteria = {
    city: document.getElementById('city'),
    pod: document.getElementById('pod'),
    status: document.getElementById('status'),
    // few more
  }

  $.post('functions/requestData.php', {selectcriteria:selectcriteria}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I have used this same method for a number of sites.  The only difference is the other sites used more JQuery to grab the values.  For example:

```
$('#requestData').on("click", function(){
  var selectcriteria = {
    city: $('#city').val(),
    // and so on
  }
});
```

That's really the only difference.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to provide the `.value` to the properties in the object you send in `$.post()`, not the entire Element object. `city: document.getElementById('city').value,`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Looks like the question was closed, but your suggestion solved my problem.  Thanks again.